# Taxonomy dropdown metabox in the back-end

Tags: wp-admin, metabox, taxonomy, dropdown

I've created custom taxonomy called `Brands` and made it hierarchical so I can add Car brands and models there and keep their relations, like this:

- Ford

  - Mustang
  - Mondeo
  - Focus

Problem is, this list might get pretty long and only one *brand* and one *model* is needed per post, so checkboxes are misleading.

I'm thinking to split that metabox in to two (one for brand and one for model) and make them dropdowns. So when brand is selected in the first dropdown, second dropdown would show only models related to that brand. But i have no idea how to code it. Maybe anyone could show me an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example. I have also created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/997350) with more generic code.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_metabox');
function my_custom_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('custom-taxonomy-dropdown','Brands','taxonomy_dropdowns_box','post','side','high');
}

function taxonomy_dropdowns_box( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field('custom-dropdown', 'dropdown-nonce');
    $terms = get_terms( 'brands', 'hide_empty=0');
    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'brands', array('fields'=>'ids'));

    // you can move the below java script to admin_head
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#custombrandoptions').change(function() {
                    var custombrand = jQuery('#custombrandoptions').val();
                    if ( custombrand == '0') {
                        jQuery('#custommodeloptions').html('');
                            jQuery('#modelcontainer').css('display', 'none');
                    } else {
                        var data = {
                            'action':'get_brand_models',
                            'custombrand':custombrand,
                            'dropdown-nonce': jQuery('#dropdown-nonce').val()
                        };
                        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
                            jQuery('#custommodeloptions').html(response);
                            jQuery('#modelcontainer').css('display', 'inline');
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    echo "Brand:";
    echo "<select id='custombrandoptions' name='custombrands[]'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>None</option>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->parent == 0) {
            if ( in_array($term->term_id, $object_terms) ) {
                $parent_id = $term->term_id;
                echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$term->name}</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</select><br />";
    echo "<div id='modelcontainer'";
    if ( !isset( $parent_id)) echo " style='display: none;'";
    echo ">";
    echo "Models:";
    echo "<select id='custommodeloptions' name='custombrands[]'>";
    if ( isset( $parent_id)) {
        $models = get_terms( 'brands', 'hide_empty=0&child_of='.$parent_id);
        foreach ( $models as $model ) {
             if ( in_array($model->term_id, $object_terms) ) {
                echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$model->name}</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}'>{$model->name}</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</div>";
}

add_action('save_post','save_my_custom_taxonomy');
function save_my_custom_taxonomy( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dropdown-nonce'], 'custom-dropdown'))
        return;

    $brands = array_map('intval', $_POST['custombrands']);
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $brands, 'brands');
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_brand_models', 'get_brand_models');
function get_brand_models() {
    check_ajax_referer('custom-dropdown', 'dropdown-nonce');
    if (isset($_POST['custombrand'])) {
        $models = get_terms( 'brands', 'hide_empty=0&child_of='. $_POST['custombrand']);
        echo "<option value='0'>Select one</option>";
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            echo "<option value='{$model->term_id}'>{$model->name}</option>";
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: @Hameedullah pretty heavy stuff hameedullah, great job nonetheless. +1

Comment: @Hameedullah very nice. But I have a problem with it. I pasted all this code to my functions.php and when I go to the post back-end, I get this:
**Warning:** _define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in_ (pointing to this line of code: `if ( define('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )`).

Comment: please change define to defined e.g `if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ))`

Comment: @Hameedullah this is great, thanks for solution :)

Comment: was excited to find this snippet and tried it on site. I am using it on a custom post-type, not posts, but do not see the metabox. are there steps needed to make this work on other post-types? ..I did change the tax name to my custom taxonomy, only using this for single tax, not multi like the original person requested

Comment: have you specified your custom post type in add_meta_box? Its the 4th argument.

Comment: Somehow I missed that one. Thanks. By any chance do you happen to have a version of this that works for a single dropdown choice? I have a simple non-hierarchical taxonomy 'speaker'. I will try editing out what is not needed in this function, though I'm not certain I will be able to nail it. Will try hard though. I could ask it in another question if that is best

Comment: Yes, a another question is the right way if you think you won't be able to do it yourself.

Comment: @Hameedullah Khan
Thank you so much, your code works like a charm! I even could to modify it to work with three levels taxonomy tree (3 drop-downs). I just miss a simple loading indicator beside the field when retrieving the drop-down values, which improves the user experience. Could that be easily added? I would appreciate if you, or anyone else, guided me. Thanks!

Comment: @Mamouneyya Please do not use answers for discussion. You will be able to leave comments when you gain some reputation on site.