# Taxonomy dropdown metabox in the back-end

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have registered my custom taxonomy and want to use dropdown in back end... 
code given here [Taxonomy dropdown metabox in the back-end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18578/taxonomy-dropdown-metabox-in-the-back-end) works like a charm.... but now in admin there are two metaboxes one is my custom which shows as drop down and another is default which takes comma seprated input similar as tags and i dont want that... So how could i remove that default meta box...

Answer (score 1):

I had [the same question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/how-do-you-remove-a-category-style-hierarchical-taxonomy-metabox).

You use the `remove_meta_box` functions mentioned in a previous answer, but you have two options: `tagsdiv-{$tax_name}` for non-hierarchical taxonomies and `{$tax_name}div` for hierarchical taxonomies (like categories).  So in your case:

```
 remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-brands', 'post', 'normal');
 remove_meta_box('brandsdiv', 'post', 'normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [remove_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box). you may need to look at the html source to verify that the div that you want to hide is called `tagsdiv-brands`, I'm pretty certain it should be correct.

```
function rajeev_remove_post_items() {
    remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-brands', 'post', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'rajeev_remove_post_items' );
```

**EDIT** - I changed the function name from `remove_post_items` to `rajeev_remove_post_items`, it's always a good idea to prefix your functions with something likely to be unique to avoid potential collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Just set [show_ui](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) to false when you register your taxonomy.